# PHP/MYSQL: Function mysqli_query() doesnt work for some reason

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

EDIT/AWNSER: It was a bloody typo, dont mind me facedesking, thanks Sadikhasan

For some reason, the function mysqli_query in my code below, doesnt work, when i open the page, it returns an error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function msqli_query() in
>   ****/****/****/****/**db.php on line 16

I double checked the script, but couldnt find any typo's or ";" misplacements, the login part works, its purly the query that derps.

```
<?php

$sqlhost = '*****';
$sqlname = '*****';
$sqlpass = '*****';
$sqldbname = '*****';

$con=mysqli_connect($sqlhost,$sqlname,$sqlpass,$sqldbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{
        echo "connection successfull!";
    }

$result = msqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM PEOPLE");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['ID'] . "<br>";
        echo $row['NAME'] . "<br>";
        echo $row['AGE'] . "<br>";
        echo $row['SEX'] . "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The names are in capitals in the database, i checked that too :)

thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: msqli_query to mysqli_query...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct spelling to `mysqli` in this line

```
$result = msqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM PEOPLE");
```

Comment: i knew it was just a bloody typo, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Now work your script?

Comment: It works flawlessly now, again, thanks for the help :)